# TypeError: _components_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        dba.collection('contact').add({
            name: name,
            email:email,
            message :message,
        })
        .then(() => {
            setOpen(true);
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            alert(error.message)
        })
      
       setName("")
       setEmail("")
       setMessage("")
       
    })
```

> when running and found an error, because the version I use is an upgrade from firebase sdk 8 which is firebase 9 compat , i confused the error because previously when I used firebase sdk 8 it ran smoothly , whats wrong from this code ?

```
TypeError: _components_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.collection is not a function
onSubmitHandler
E:/FRS/react-firestore/src/components/Contact.jsx:49
  46 | 
  47 |    const onSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
  48 |        e.preventDefault()
> 49 |        dba.collection('contact').add({
     | ^  50 |            name: name,
  51 |            email:email,
  52 |            message :message,
```

> Firebase.js sdk 9 modular

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from './config';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const dba = getFirestore(firebaseApp)

export default dba;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @SteffenFrank I'm confused about the error that occurred because previously when I used firebase sdk 8 it ran smoothly

Comment: May be typescript tried to invoke js file, but not ts. If you have js file in same place where in ts file, you can delete js file and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your firebase.js file, it might help you :

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

  export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

  export const realtime = firebase.database();

  export default firebase;
```

And import firestore from firebase.js in your first file.Like,

```
import {firestore} from './Firebase';
```

And then add

```
firestore.collection("your_collection_name").doc('document_name').set({
name: name, email: email,
})      
        .then(() =>{
            alert(`Data recorded.`)
            setData({
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    };
```